# efficient import export of modules with webpack and babel-loader - tree shaking not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, babel-loader

I am having an issue that we have imported modules which were not imported in controllers.

module1.js

```
export default class Module1 {}
```

module2.js

```
export default class Module2 {}
```

index.js

```
export { default as Module1 } from "./module1.js";
export { default as Module2 } from "./module2.js";
```

Controller:

```
import { Module1 } from "index.js"
```

I would presume that only Module1 is imported, but when I go over the code I also see Module2 code in a bundle.

Webapack:

```
 {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        ["env", {
                            "modules": false
                    }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
```

Comment: wild guess  on collaborating package ... https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import  in 'options.presets.plugins'  == ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]

Comment: Module2 is still imported.

Comment: It is webpack's issue not babels on my further investigation.